# Custom routing in anchor tag helper with ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, url, routes, location

In my controller I am using route:

```
[Route("/{culture}/contact")]
//action signature
```

So I need to use a `culture` parameter. When entering directly url: `https://localhost:44361/en/contact` in the browser it is displayed same url, and it is fine.

In `cshtml` I am using an anchor such as:

```
<a class="mainButton" rel="canonical" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Contact" asp-route-culture ="@ViewBag.Culture">contact</a>
```

And the anchor produces me an url in the browser: `https://localhost:44361/contact?culture=en`

How to make my anchor to produce this? `https://localhost:44361/en/contact`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end of the day I used approach where I am sending from the controller an `ViewBag` with culture code, and constructing the url in the view as follows:

`<div><a class="mainButton" rel="canonical" hreflang="@ViewBag.Culture" href="/@ViewBag.Culture/services">@Localizer["services"]</a></div>`

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to inherit the RequestCultureProvider class.

There is another one way to have the same result using the built-in RouteDataRequestCultureProvider class (it has been introduced in ASP.NET Core 1.1).

You can refer to this article.

[ASP.NET Core Culture Route Parameter](https://medium.com/@dmitrysikorsky/asp-net-core-culture-route-parameter-4e1310cabacc)